# How to modify parameter file in MRTSwath for bulk data processing?

Tags: modis-reprojection-tool

I need to create a parameter file for bulk data processing in MRTSwath Tool. I have the basic script written but there is issue in modifying it so that it automatically picks the input files from a folder and processes it according to the given parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to modify the parameter file on the fly. Instead, when you call the swath2grid.exe, you can use the `-if=` switch to set the input file, the `-gf=` switch to set the geolocation file, and the `-of=` switch to set the output file, while keeping all the other parameters from the specified `.prm` file.

An example from a .bat file used for processing a large number of MOD02QKM / MOD03 files:

```
set MRTSWATH_HOME="c:\MODIS\MRTSwath"
set MRTSWATH_DATA_DIR="c:\MODIS\MRTSwath\data"
set Path="c:\MODIS\MRTSwath\bin;%Path%"
swath2grid.exe -pf=D:\Data\ParameterFile.prm -if=D:\Data\MODIS\MOD02QKM.A2014001.0305.006.2014001100215.hdf -gf=D:\Data\MODIS\MOD03.A2014001.0305.006.2014001100215.hdf -of=D:\Data\MODIS\GTiff\M02\MOD2QKM.A2014001.0305.006.tif
swath2grid.exe -pf=D:\Data\ParameterFile.prm -if=D:\Data\MODIS\MOD02QKM.A2014002.0210.006.2014002093634.hdf -gf=D:\Data\MODIS\MOD03.A2014002.0210.006.2014002093634.hdf -of=D:\Data\MODIS\GTiff\M02\MOD2QKM.A2014002.0210.006.tif
```

Generating the full `.bat` file can be done using scripts or software like Excel.

Comment: I have saved a parameter file in IDLE and have some information about creating the batch file in Linux but I need to make it in windows, is there any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: It is a rather cumbersome process to document how to do it, but using cmd-prompt, a couple of commands like: 'dir /b /s MOD09*.hdf > list.txt', Excel and some search and replace can do it. If I have time for it, I'll look into writing a small guide, but it won't be within the next few weeks.